how to show the Notebook tab in Kaggle
I am facing an issue with my Kaggle notebook interface. The "Notebook" tab, which is usually located on the right side of the notebook, is somehow hidden in my account. This tab, as shown in the attached image, is essential for accessing various options and inputs, but I am currently unable to see it.
I have tried several methods to get it back but have been unlucky. How do i get it back?


I found this little arrow sign in the bottom right corner of the screen that shows the tab.

